# Executing MYSQL Stored Procedures using DBVisualizer

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dbvisualizer

I am using DBVisualizer for the first time. I have made a stored procedure in mysql database. However I am unable to execute it from DBVisualizer.

This is how the procedure looks like. Here `//` is used as delimiter. I have four columns in the table namely `slno int` (autoincrement), `time timestamp`, `price int`, and `prodid varchar`.

```
*DROP PROCEDURE `spTest`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spTest`()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM dummy1 where prodid=pr01;
END*
```

In DBVisualizer, I am executing `@call spTest()`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As the definer of the stored procedure is root, your DBVizualizer connection to MySQL must be as the root user in order to execute it.